# Automated authentication to Private Docker Registry

Tags: authentication, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-registry

I have a private docker registry hosted on GitLab.
I need to support accessing this registry automatically (via Gitlab CI), but I don't want to use developer credentials (insecure and requires changing them every time a dev leaves the company).

How are others authenticating?

Do you create an "API Account" to authenticate with?  Docker doesn't seem to support service account keys or other methods of authentication.

Thank you

Edit:
[GitLab CI ssh registry login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267827/gitlab-ci-ssh-registry-login?rq=1)

The accepted answer here answered the question for GitLab.

However, I would like to know if there is any alternatives, since this still only allows ephemeral keys while doing the deployment via GitLab CI

Comment: Why don't you use the `CI_JOB_TOKEN`? `docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY`

Comment: I mentioned that answer, but that is applicable only to GitLab. Are there other authentication methods when not using an integrated CI/CD system like gitlab?

Comment: Some registries like quay.io may provide an alternative login strategy(they provide an API token) but this highly dependent on the provider itself, as far as I know docker hub doesn't have any other authentication strategies for example. If you spin up your own private registry of course you'd be able to customize this